# 'Remembering' a variable when using a recursive algorithm?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dynamic-programming

I have this code:

```
def function(pos):
    new_list = []

    if condition:
        for x in range(0,len(another_list)):
            new_pos = another_list[x]
            new_list.append(new_pos)
            function(new_pos)
```

where `another_list` is a list that is defined elsewhere, and I can access it.

When the given position meets a certain `condition`, I'm looping through `another_list` and I'm adding positions, but of course everytime I call `function`, `new_list` gets reset and all the values in it are removed.

I want to have `new_list` contain all the `new_pos` values and not get reset each time `function` gets called, and I only want it to be cleared when I tell it to. How should I achieve this?

Comment: You thought of putting `new_list = []` outside the function?

Comment: @Wright What would happen if one wanted to run the function a second time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is typically done by adding an argument to the function to hold the "remembered" value and giving it a default value so it doesn't have to be provided to the upper-most level call. The function can return this value as shown if it's that type of function (as opposed to one that is executed only for its side-effects).

```
def function(pos, new_list=None):
    if new_list is None:
        new_list = []

    if condition:
        for x in range(0,len(another_list)):
            new_pos = another_list[x]
            new_list.append(new_pos)
            function(new_pos, new_list)

    return new_list

# same usage
pos = 42
result_list = function(pos)
```

Comment: Since it doesn't appear that the lower function calls need to access `new_list`, it might be more clear in this case to `return new_list + function(new_pos)`. However, I also use this approach when the lower calls need to access an object. I'd be happy to delete my answer if you incorporated that solution into your answer (or, perhaps there's a reason why my answer is insufficient).

Comment: @Jared: `function()` is its own "lower function call" because it's recursive and it needs access to `new_list` so it can append something to it—so what you're saying doesn't make sense to me in this case.

Comment: Right, but in the case where only appending is done, one could instead construct a new list in the function and *extend* the "upper function" list with the new list. Of course, if something other than appending is necessary, this won't work.

Comment: @Jared: Seems like constructing a new list for each level of recursion would much more expensive than necessary—although it would work I suppose (and be appropriate if something like a simple sum was being produced as opposed to populating a mutable container.

Comment: In general, appending to an existing list is much faster in python than constructing an aggregation of multiple lists. Consider what happens when this function has to recurse 500 times - hint: all those lists need to be held on the stack and are only aggregated when the recursion ends. This may not be the case in other languages with explicit support for tail recursion (what this simulates). +1 for that reason.

Comment: Excuse me for the late reply, your method works great!

Answer (score 0):

I thought this might help you.

```
def function(first_pos):

    def foo(pos):
        if condition:
            for x in range(0, len(another_list)):
                new_pos = another_list[x]
                new_list.append(new_pos)
                foo(new_pos)

    new_list = []
    foo(first_pos)
    return new_list
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to accumulate the result of each function call, you could change the last line of your function to:

```
return new_list + function(new_pos)
```

Then, you'll also want to add a `return new_list` in the case where `condition` is not satisfied.

A generic recursive function of this nature might look like:

```
def generic_function(param):

    # break recursion when condition is not met
    if not condition:
        return []

    else:
        temporary_list = []
        # do stuff
        return temporary_list + generic_function(new_param)
```

This might be a better approach than trying to "remember" an object down through the recursion. If it turns out that is truly necessary, see [martineau's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43661393/2247550) which addresses that problem.

Answer (score -1):

`new_list=[]` needs to be an argument with a default value in your function, so you pass it through to the next call, but when you call it the first time it defaults to an empty list

Comment: It's a very poor practice to assign a mutable value to default argument because whatever its value each time it's used will be come it default value the next time you call it.